# Magento: Is it safe to override event observer core class?

Tags: php, events, magento, overriding, observer-pattern

Suppose, there is an event observer class in core. I can override it. But, is it safe? I mean, does it affect other functions of the observer class?

Like, if there are two functions in core observer class and I did override only one function. Then, will the other function work safely as before.

I think it is similar to model override and should be safe. Am I right?

**Edit**:-

For example,

- There is a class **CoreClassA** in core.
- There is a function **coreFunctionA** in **CoreClassA**.
- An event **core_event_a** is dispatched in this **coreFunctionA**.
- Another core module **CoreModuleB** is creating event observer with **core_event_a**.
- So, whenever **core_event_a** is dispatched, **CoreModuleB**'s event observer is called.
- Suppose, **CoreModuleB**'s event observer contains two functions. One for **core_event_a** dispatch action (let us name it **eventDispatchA**) and another for some other event dispatch action (let's say **eventDispatchX**).
- In my custom module, I want to override **eventDispatchA**. *Basically, I want to change the some code in eventDispatchA or, I may just want to skip/omit this function*. I can override it. *But, will it affect **eventDispatchX** if I do so? Or, is there any other better way instead of overriding event observer?*

Comment: can you tell us why you want to override the class?  There might be a better way to achieve the same effect

Comment: Edited. I hope I did not make it more complex. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it will but if you override something that others might be using it's always worth to make something similar:

```
    public function samefunction($object){
        if(mymodueleisused){
            //do your different thing
        } else {
           return parent::samefunction();
        }
    }
```

and as others have told you : "if you are in need to change/override the core then you are probably doing it wrong" and it's better to ask in different manner by describing what you want to do and why

Comment: Thanks. I am asking for a general overview. When I override the Observer, I will be extending its core class. So, I think it will not affect other functions of the core class.

Comment: depends, if you extend and override a method then it certainly will, if you add new methods and those are not called from core methods then not

Comment: nice touch to test which module is using the override